# Wordpress - current_user_can in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am trying to run a simple if statement inside the wp-functions.php file and am using `current_user_can`. However I get PHP errors like: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function current_user_can() in..."

If anyone could take a look at my code, that would be much appreciated.

The code I am using is here:

```
        global $current_user_can;
        if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
            /* Admin User */

        } else {
            /* Member */
            echo "<p>something</p>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because pluggable.php is not loaded by some reason. Try to add this before your function;

```
if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) { include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); }
```

It just checks if pluggable is loaded, and if not, it includes it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check directly the role of the member, you can use this code:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if( !in_array( 'administrator', $current_user->roles ) ) {
 //Do something
} else {
 //Do something else
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I wanted to set up a function so that a script runs if the user is an admin, but not if they are anything else. Would the code above do this especially if there are multiple admins?

Comment: Just add get_currentuserinfo(); above your current code, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I get another error: Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo()

Comment: Using all of your above code, I get:  Call to undefined function get_currentuserinfo()  Do I need to include the other php files?

Comment: Try to add this at the top of your functions.php: `require_once('/wp-includes/pluggable-functions.php');`

Comment: I added that successfully and now get this: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in xxxxxxx on line 119

Comment: Are you coding a plugin or a theme from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating a plugin, you must have to include like

```html
if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) { include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); }// no need to add for theme functions
global $current_user_can;
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        // your stuff here
}
```